# Quartic to biquadratic

Tags: polynomials

*If* $$ x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4} $$ *are the roots of a general quartic equation such that,*
         
   $$  x_{1}\ +\ x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}\ =\ 0 $$
 
   $$  \frac{1}{x_{1}}\ +\ \frac{1}{x_{2}}\ +\ \frac{1}{x_{3}}\ +\ \frac{1}{x_{4}}\ =\ 0 $$
 *how do I prove that the quartic equation transforms into a biquadratic one such that it has roots  $$ x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4} $$ where  
$$ x_{1}= -x_{3} $$ 
$$ x_{2}= -x_{4}$$?*

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck? Hint: the sum of the roots being zero means that the quartic has no term in $x^3$ by Vieta's relations. Repeat and conclude.

Comment: But what about the term in x??

Comment: You are given two conditions, and have only used one of them so far. See what the other one is telling you.

Comment: Oh yes if I multiply the second expression with the product of the roots then the sum of product of roots taken three at a time will be equal to 0... So by Vieta's relation coefficient of x will be 0.. Thanks for leading me to the realization . I usually remember only sum of roots expression and product of roots expression from Vieta's relation so it took me time to get that.